# Visual basic - Access to path denied

Tags: visual-studio, express, path, access-denied, build-error

I'm writing a project in Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition, which used to work completely fine until that moment, when I decided to install MS Chart Control in order to create a diagram in my project.
This didn't work (error "failed to register activex control" when dragging the tool into the form; although I registered everything successfully as an administrator) and many hours googling myself through forums made it clear to me, that this seems to be a general bug. At least I couldn't find a solution.

So now, I removed the tool MS Chart Control again, but still, I get error messages, when I build my project. After reinstalling Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition completely and removing all references that pointed on the MS Chart Library, I managed to delete some of them.

However three errors still remain, when I build the project. All of them of the same kind:

"Cannot write to the output file "C:...\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Test\Test\obj\Debug\Test.Form1.resources".
Access to the path 'C:...\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Test\Test\obj\Debug\Test.Form1.resources' is denied."
(same thing with two other files in the Debug-folder)

I again spent several hours searching through forums, but could not find a helpful answer. I already tried reinstalling everything again as well as rebooting windows and emptying the bin.
I also made sure, that the folder properties of 'Debug' are set on 'full access'.

Still, Visual Basic can not write on these files anymore.

I would be very grateful for any answer. Please note, that I am not an expert, neither on programming nor on computer-troubleshooting, so I would be happy about generally understandable (step-by-step) answers.

Many thanks in advance!

Regards,
c.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out, that it works, if I open Visual Basic Studio as an administrator.
Strange, because a month ago, it always worked fine and I don't think I have changed anything about the folder or datas properties.

Anyway.... that solved the problem, I guess.